# Setting absolute position left in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, css-position

I am trying to set my gridview (asp.net) position to absolute when the gridview stretches further than the standard 960 pixels.

However I have run across the issue where `left: 0` has the effect I desire, however anything other than that does nothing.

Here is my code. The section where it's less than the screen doesnt work because i am trying to center it to the screen. However as it's greater than 0 the absolute position of `Left: x` doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 var gridview = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
            var fieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");
            fieldset[0].style.position = "relative";
            for (var i = 0; i < gridview.length; i++) {
                var width = gridview[i].offsetWidth;
                var screenWidth = window.screen.width - 2;

                if (width > 940) {
                    gridview[i].style.position = "absolute";
                    if (width > screenWidth) {
                        gridview[i].style.left = 0;
                        alert('> screen');
                    }
                    else {
                        gridview[i].style.left = 50;
                        alert('< screen');
                    }
                }
            }
```

EDIT: The fix was to concat 'px' after the value

Comment: I recommend creating a simple example that demonstrates the problem. I'm not sure there is enough to go on in your example, but a http://jsfiddle.net might help.

Comment: You have to concatenate the unit (probably `px`) after the value you're setting.

Comment: Thank you! it was that i had to concat px after it, such a stupid mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really go enough to go on, but it might be the case that the container of gridview hasn't had its position set your css.

To use the `postion:absolute` the above container should be set to `position:relative` or it just wont render the css.

Also try adding px to the end of your size, setting the css to left:XXpx; rather than just a  number.